# LXD Cannot Bridge network device

Tags: maas, lxc, lxd

I'm trying, (and failing) to use LXD and MaaS on my home machine to create a Pod. I commisioned and deploy a machine via MaaS on my local network. When I ssh into it I install LXD and bridge-utils. When I try to create a Pod, my host machine cannot connect.
I tried creating the maas user on my other machine, along with creating the bridge.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that you installed LXD. Normally, LXD is pre-installed in the Ubuntu images. Which exact images (and versions) did you use?

You mention installing `bridge-utils`. What network configuration changes did you do?

(could not add a comment above because I do not have enough karma points)